# Риторический вопрос о том как разобратся в Bundle

Tags: php, symfony2, bundles

*Недавно на **symfony2** давно хотел этот опыт, и поэтому не жалуюсь и почти всем доволен.*

Меня огорчает скудное описание бандлов и примеров по работе с ними. Хорошо когда бандл был внедрен до тебя и перед тобой есть работающий код на основе которого достаточно просто разобраться как с этим работать.
Единственное верное решение, как по мне, это читать код сущностей и контроллеров бандлов. Но с огромными бандлами зачастую это лишь добавляет вопросов.

Пример [docs.sylius](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/)
Достаточно объемный бандл и имеет сложную иерархическую структуру и не объемное описаине

Возможно я не с той стороны подхожу к изучению вопроса и я тут один такой. Подскажите как и с помощью чего изучить мат.часть по инструментам? Возможно есть доки о которых я не знаю, так как сразу лезу в официальные материалы. Возможно нужно находить примеры использования бандлов `github`. Так как изучение контроллеров и тестов которые идут в пакетах не всегда помогает

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Многие разработчики open-source проектов не утруждают себя написанием документации, поэтому, ничего лучше, чем метод научного тыка, гугление (по ключевым словам, по названиям функций, классов), чтение форумов (иногда решение можно найти в темах, которые не имеют прямого отношения к вашему вопросу), нельзя придумать.

При работе с Symfony2 чтение громоздкого кода фреймворка и бандлов с огромным количеством классов мне, честно говоря, слабо помогало.
Зачастую, чтобы создать собрать по крупицам рабочий код, мне приходилось долго сидеть в дебаггере (xdebug+phpstorm), выясняя, как работает тот или иной метод, что он ожидает на входе, что он возвращает. Таким образом я узнавал многие недокументированные вещи.

Comment: это подтверждает что проблема не во мне, и что я делаю все правильно. Но не добавляет, к сожалению, к облегчению этого пути